# Move directory contents up one level without using mv/cp/find/

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Often, after downloading and uncompressing a compressed folder, one ends up with a folder structure like this:

```
.
└── downloaded
    └── downloaded
        ├── a
        ├── b
        ├── c
        └── d
```

I know I could just do something similar to `mv downloaded/downloaded/* downloaded && rmdir downloaded/downloaded`. However I remember once following a tutorial, where the author used a command, let's call it `xyz`, to move the contents of `downloaded/downloaded` to `downloaded` and after that delete `downloaded/downloaded` automatically like this: `xyz downloaded/downloaded`.

I just forgot the name of the command as well as the tutorial I found it in. It is very useful in my opinion though.

My question is: Do you know the command name?

I stumbled across a few questions where people asked how to move folder content up one level, but none of the questions had an answer that contained the specific command I'm looking for.

Comment: I wrote a python script called `volcano` once (still use it regularly), that causes all files  in sub folders within a directory root (minus those in the exclude list) to "erupt" out, into the root dir. My point is simply that this is not likely to be a common system command, but instead someones script.

Comment: @FrankThomas I use fedora and it worked without installing anything as far as I remember... But thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
tar --remove-files -cC downloaded{,} | tar -x
```

(This is not as simple as your exemplary `xyz downloaded/downloaded` but notice that `downloaded` is typed only once.)

#### Explanation:

At first `downloaded{,}` is expanded by `bash` to `downloaded downloaded`, so the command is equivalent to:

```
tar -c --remove-files -C downloaded downloaded | tar -x
```

Meaning in sequence:

- `tar -c` – create an archive…
- `--remove-files` – …(but remove files and directories after adding)…
- `-C downloaded` – …with working directory changed to (the outer) `downloaded`;
- `downloaded` – add (the inner) `downloaded` to the archive;
- `|` – then pipe the archive to…
- `tar -x` – …another `tar` ordered to extract it.